# Check IP with JWT Authorization in ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to check the IP adress when using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` in an ASP.NET core Web Api application?

I thought about adding a Claim containing the IP of the user that requested it and check it somehow for each request. Normally I would use `OnActionExecuting` in ASP.NET MVC.

Is there a Middleware/Authorization based solution?

I Create my Jwt Token Claims like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Claim> getStandardClaims(IdentityUser user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim("ipaddress", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString())
    };

    return claims;
}
```

this is what the JWT Data look like:

```
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "username",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "5a6b3eb8-ed7f-48c6-b10c-a279ffd4f7c8",
  "sub": "username",
  "jti": "44c95b53-bfba-4f33-b4c3-834127605432",
  "ipaddress": "::1",
  "exp": 1542707081,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001/",
  "aud": "https://localhost:5001/"
}
```

Edit: Possible Solution for JWT Claims?
Maybe I have to read the Claims like this (Test code, no null checks ect..):

```
var auth = HttpContext.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Authorization");
string token = auth.Value[0].Split(' ')[1];

JwtTokenService<RefreshToken, string> jwtService = new JwtTokenService<RefreshToken, string>(null);
var principal = jwtService.GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(token, _config["Jwt:Key"]);

Claim ipClaim = principal.FindFirst(claim => claim.Type == "ipaddress");
```

This is the GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken Method:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(string token, string securityKey)
{
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false, 
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey)),
        ValidateLifetime = false 
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SecurityToken securityToken;
    var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);
    var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
    if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");

    return principal;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that (and all other authorization stuff) via [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

```
public class IpCheckRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public bool IpClaimRequired { get; set; } = true;
}

public class IpCheckHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IpCheckRequirement>
{
    public IpCheckHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    private IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }
    private HttpContext HttpContext => HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;


    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IpCheckRequirement requirement)
    {
        Claim ipClaim = context.User.FindFirst(claim => claim.Type == "ipaddress");

        // No claim existing set and and its configured as optional so skip the check
        if(ipClaim == null && !requirement.IpClaimRequired)
        {
            // Optional claims (IsClaimRequired=false and no "ipaddress" in the claims principal) won't call context.Fail()
            // This allows next Handle to succeed. If we call Fail() the access will be denied, even if handlers
            // evaluated after this one do succeed
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        if (ipClaim.Value = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString())
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            // Only call fail, to guarantee a failure, even if further handlers may succeed
            context.Fail();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

then add

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, IpCheckHandler>();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SameIpPolicy",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new IpCheckRequirement { IpClaimRequired = true }));
});
```

to your `ConfigureServices` method.

Now you can annote the controllers on which you want to apply it with `[Authroize(Policy = "SameIpPolicy")]` or add a global policy:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("SameIpPolicy"))
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I get the idea and the `HandleRequirementAsync` method gets triggered. But `context.User.FindFirst` gives me the user Claims for the Identity instance I guess? I need the claims I've put into my JWT token (see original post on how I add these claims. The JWT Authorization works fine btw.

Comment: Then you have an odd setup. Typically your Identity server (which generates the JWT token) and your resource server are two distinct applications. In resource servers (WebAPIs only, no MVC) you usually use JWT for authorization and Cookie authorization for MVC. Did you really call the given method via Ajax (or postman or other addon) with the JWT bearer token included in the request?

Comment: Yes, I use Postman. Using no token gives me an unauthorized error code. In my setup there is just one server. I edited my post, added a "possible" solution. This way I can read the claims from the jwt. At the moment my Identity User has no claims set. I don't want to hit the database. But I guess I would have to add Identity Claims and sync them with my JWT and update the IP Adress for the ip claim?!

Comment: I think something wrong with your (default) authentication scheme. The authentication scheme tells the system whose claim to use (in case you have more than one authentication in use). If you set up Cookie authentication scheme as default it will always use its claims, not the one from JWT. Either you set JWT auth schema as default, and annotate  Cookie/Identity where needed `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes  = "CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme")]`.

Comment: See the docs for more about authorization schemes: [Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: Mhh okay, I have this in my Startup: `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` + `AddJwtBearer()` ... I am using ASP.NET Identity to check if the user is in the database + Password. But I guess this shouldn't be a problem?!

Comment: Added it like this: `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()` and us it like this in my login method: `_signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false);`

Comment: Dunno, hard to guess what's exactly wired wrong in your case. I typically have Authentication server and resource server as separate issues, avoids issues with scaleability of the resource server and such issues doesn't happen there. I'd suggest posting a new question on this and provide enough information on how your identity/jwt token generation/authorization i set up

Comment: I am about to setup a minimal complete example. I will try to setup your policy again and see if it works.

Comment: Okay it's working now. Maybe it has something to do with using Asp.NET Identity. I have to experiment a little bit. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I changed some stuff in my code (added Identity Stuff and removed it) and got a 403 when the policy was checked. I don't know why but adding a `context.Succeed(requirement);` when the IP is correct works now again. Shouldn't it be there in any case?

Comment: Yea, sorry. Missed it on my part. Yes, you need to call `context.Succeed(requirement);` if you want it evaluate as success. But only call `.Fail()` if you want guarantee it to fail (other authorization handlers wont be evaluated for this requirement). By not calling `.Fail()` you allow next handler to succeed. See [Why would I want multiple handlers for a requirement?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1#why-would-i-want-multiple-handlers-for-a-requirement)

Answer (score 1):

For @Tseng solution,
Set Default Policy

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("SAME_IP_POLICY", i => i.Requirements.Add(new IpCheckRequirement { IpClaimRequired = true }));
            options.DefaultPolicy = options.GetPolicy("SAME_IP_POLICY") ?? options.DefaultPolicy;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with @Tseng solution by applying [Authorize(Policy = "SameIpPolicy")] on each controller, thanks a lot man !
Just to correct one typo mistake :

Missing semi colon :

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("SameIpPolicy"));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(claim => claim.Type == "ipaddr")